# TSQL - dynamic WHERE clause to check for NULL for certain columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, null, sql-server-2012

Using Sql Server 2012 I want to query a table to only fetch rows where certain columns are not null or don't contain an empty string.

The columns I need to check for null and ' ' all start with either **col_as** or **col_m** followed by two digits.

At the moment I write `where col_as01 is not null or` ....
which becomes difficult to maintain due to the quantity of columns I have to check.

Is there a more elegant way to do this? Some kind of looping?

I also use ISNULL(NULLIF([col_as01], ''), Null) AS [col_as01] in the select stmt to get rid of the empty string values.

thank you for your help.

Comment: A comparison against a known string implicitly excludes null values, so if you have something like `WHERE Value = '<somethingorevennothing>'` that wont return you any null results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should fill in the blanks.

```
select 
    @myWhereString =stuff((select 'or isnull('+COLUMN_NAME+','''') = '''' ' as [text()] 
                       from Primebet.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                       where TABLE_NAME = 'YourTable'
                           and (column_name like 'col_as%'
                                or
                                column_name like 'col_m%')
                       for xml path('')),1,3,'')
set @myWhereString ='rest of your query'+ @myWhereString

exec executesql with your query
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

`WHERE DATALENGTH(col_as01) > 0`

That will implicitly exclude null values, and the length greater 0 will guarantee you to retrieve non empty strings.

PS: You could also use `LEN` instead of `DATALENGTH` but that will trim spaces in your string at the beginning and end so you would not get values that only contain spaces then.

Answer (score 0):

Simple as this:

```
WHERE  col_as01 > ''
```

Comment: Just to add some detail to this, this will exclude strings that only contain spaces, just like the comparison against `LEN(stringValue)`

Comment: @DrCopyPaste except this can use indexes (as a function is not being applied to the column) `;-)`

Comment: indexes can also use functions ;)